# How can i change my emulator word type color? in flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

Hey i cant see my words when i type anything in my app. How can i change my emulator word type color?

Comment: Can you share you code-snippet that you are working on?

Answer (score 0):

Change the color of the text:

```
TextField(
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  //decoration: InputDecoration(fillColor: Colors.orange, filled: true),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `TextFormField` with `Theme` or change `data>textSelectionTheme`  and `textTheme> subtitle1:TextStyle` on `MaterialApp`.

**Simple Way only TextColor controll**

```
  TextFormField(
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
```

**Wraping with Theme**

```
Theme(
              data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
                  selectionColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.3),
                ),
                textTheme: TextTheme(
                  subtitle1: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: TextFormField(),
            ),
```

**On MaterialApp**

```
 return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
        textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
          selectionColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.3),
        ),
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          subtitle1: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Body(),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change its from them textSelectionTheme.
See this link https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/text-selection-theme